# DAX: How to sum two LOOKUPVALUE columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table C with a LOOKUPVALUE column from table A and another LOOKUPVALUE column from table B.

I would like to add another column, which is the sum of the two columns.

When I try to use a DAX Sum formula, I get error: The SUM function only accepts a column reference as an argument.

I tried to demonstrate visually what I am trying to do here :[Visual of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxE2p.jpg)

Comment: Provide your table sample data here in tabular format. Image is not a good practice for sharing sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your measure/column-

```
TOTAL = SUM(TOGETHER(BATMAN) + TOGETHER(ROBIN))
```

Can you please try with -

```
TOTAL = TOGETHER(BATMAN) + TOGETHER(ROBIN)
```

**Note:** Guess BATMAN and ROBIN both are custom columns in your table